# Regex matching Cisco interface

Tags: regex, networking, cisco

I am trying to match Cisco's interface names and split it up. The regex i have so far is:

```
(\D+)(\d+)(?:\/)?(\d+)?(?:\.)?(\d+)?
```

This matches:

```
FastEthernet9
FastEthernet9/5
FastEthernet9/5.10
```

The problem i have is that it also matches:

```
FastEthernet9.10
```

Any ideas on how to make it so it does not match? Bonus points if it can match:

```
tengigabitethernet0/0/0.20
```

**Edit:**

Okay. I am trying to split this string up into groups for use in python. In the cisco world the first part of the string `FastEthernet` is the type of interface, the first zero is the slot in the equipment the zero efter the slash is the port number and the one after the dot is a sub-interface.

Because of how regex works i can't get dynamic groups like `(?:\/?\d+)+` to match all numbers in `/0/0/0` by them selves, but i only get the last match.

My current regex `(\D+)(\d+)(?:((?:\/?\d+)+)?(?:(?:\.)?(\d+))?)` builds on murgatroid99's but groups all `/0/0/0` together, for splitting in python.

My current result in python with this regex is `[('tengigabitethernet', '0', '/0/0', '10')]`. This seems to be how close i can get.

Comment: Can you describe what distinguishes a correct interface name from an incorrect one?

Comment: The incorrect one don't have a slash in it but have a period followed by a number like "FastEthernet9.10". The problem for me is that i have always wanted dynamic groups in regex. So I can match one group multiple times and get all the matches, not just the last one.

Comment: I mean in general. Unless you only want to match those 4 strings, you must have a more general description of what you're trying to match. Does my answer do what you want? If not, what does it do wrong?

Comment: Okay. I am trying to split this string up into groups for use in python. In the cisco world the first part of the string "FastEthernet" is the type of interface, the first zero is the slot in the equipment the zero efter the slash is the port number and the one after the dot is a sub-interface.

Because of how regex works i can't get dynamic groups like "(?:\/?\d+)+" to match all numbers in /0/0/0 by them selves, but i only get the last match.

Comment: OK, first, if you want to only match numbers, you have to put a capturing group around the numbers. Second, If you put a `?` after the `/` in your group it literally defeats the entire purpose of making that larger group because your current regex matches the one string you said not to match. Also, you're right that you can't match multiple groups in the same regex group. You're going to have to do something outside of regex to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression for matching these names (Removing unnecessary capturing groups for clarity) is:

```
\D+\d+((/\d+)+(\.\d+)?)?
```

To break it up, `\D+` matches the part of the string before the first number (such as `FastEthernet` and `\d+` matches the first number (such as `10`). Then the rest of the pattern is optional. `/\d+` matches a forward slash followed by a number, so `(/\d+)+` matches any number of repetitions of that (such as `/0/0`). Finally, `(\.\d+)?` optionally matches the period followed by a number at the end.

The important difference that makes this pattern match your specification is that in the final optional group, we get at least one `(/\d+)` before the `(\.\d)`.